# Why cheerio comments php (and other) tags when parse

Tags: cheerio

I need to show `<?php` parts of the string as inline html in my node app, but after `cherrio.load` string becomes to have html comment - `<!--?php`

```
    const $ = cheerio.load('<?php echo "example"; ?>')
    console.log($.html()) // <!--?php echo "example"; ?-->
```

Comment: Cheerio is for html/xml, not php.

Comment: @pguardiario I use it for html that contains inline code elements (<pre>, <code>), that contains `<?php` )

Comment: Right, that's not valid html though.

Comment: Possible [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/399876). Why do you think using Cheerio to parse PHP is necessary? If you share your fundamental problem this is supposed to solve, folks can provide a better way to solve it.